# Cython use of cinit()

Tags: cython

I have:

```
      cdef class BaseClass():
           def __cinit__(self,char* name):
               print "BaseClass __cinit__()"
               #...
           def __dealloc__():
               print "BaseClass __dealloc__()"
               #...
      cdef class DerClass(BaseClass):
           def __cinit__(self,char* name,int n):
               print "DerClass __cinit__()"
               #...
           def __dealloc__():
               print "DerClass __dealloc__()"
               #...
```

when i call the DerClass in cyhton happen that the construcor of the BaseClass is called automatically,what it has to print is:

```
       BaseClass __cinit__()
       DerClass __cinit__()
       DerClass __dealloc__()
       BaseClass __dealloc__()
```

but it does not,it crash ones that i call the DerClass('Ciao').
why does happen so and how can i avoid calling the **cinit** of BaseClass.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The above answer may not pose quite the best solution. Reading the section "Initialisation methods: __cinit__() and __init__()" of the link above gives this information:

> If your extension type has a base type, the `__cinit__()` method of the base type is automatically called before your `__cinit__()` method is called; you cannot explicitly call the inherited `__cinit__()` method.

and

> If you anticipate subclassing your extension type in Python, you may find it useful to give the `__cinit__()` method * and ** arguments so that it can accept and ignore extra arguments.

So my solution would be to just replace the arguments of `__cinit()__` in `BaseClass` so that a variable number of arguments can be passed to any derived class:

```
cdef class BaseClass:
    def __cinit__(self, *argv): 
        print "BaseClass __cinit__()"
        #...
def __dealloc__(self):
        print "BaseClass __dealloc__()"
        #...

cdef class DerClass(BaseClass):
    def __cinit__(self,char* name, int n):
        print "DerClass __cinit__()"
        #...
    def __dealloc__(self):
        print "DerClass __dealloc__()"
        #...
```

See [here](http://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/) for an explanation of the `*args` variable in python

Answer (score 4):

Well, you are right that you should see the **cinit** method called on your parent class.  It says so right here in the docs.

http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/special_methods.html

Here is what I tried using:

```
cdef class BaseClass:
   def __cinit__(self,char* name):
       print "BaseClass __cinit__()"
       #...
   def __dealloc__(self):
       print "BaseClass __dealloc__()"
       #...
cdef class DerClass(BaseClass):
   def __cinit__(self,char* name,int n):
       print "DerClass __cinit__()"
       #...
   def __dealloc__(self):
       print "DerClass __dealloc__()"
       #...
```

It compiled but it gave me this error when I tried to run it:

```
mike@computer:~/testing$ python runner.py 
DerClass __dealloc__()
BaseClass __dealloc__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runner.py", line 4, in <module>
    DerClass('Ciao', 1)
  File "test.pyx", line 2, in test.BaseClass.__cinit__ (test.c:488)
    def __cinit__(self,char* name):
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)
mike@computer:~/testing$
```

So I changed BaseClass.**cinit** to also take the "int n" parameter that DerClass.**cinit** does:

```
cdef class BaseClass:
   def __cinit__(self, char * name, int n):
       print "BaseClass __cinit__()"
       #...
   def __dealloc__(self):
       print "BaseClass __dealloc__()"
       #...
cdef class DerClass(BaseClass):
   def __cinit__(self,char* name,int n):
       print "DerClass __cinit__()"
       #...
   def __dealloc__(self):
       print "DerClass __dealloc__()"
       #...
```

And now it seems to work fine:

```
mike@computer:~/testing$ python runner.py 
BaseClass __cinit__()
DerClass __cinit__()
DerClass __dealloc__()
BaseClass __dealloc__()
mike@computer:~/testing$
```

Here is my runner.py file:

```
from test import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DerClass('Ciao', 1)
```