# cython c++ class inheritance cannot instantiate a derived class

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, cython

I am trying to wrap some c++ classes with Cython. For Base Classes everything works fine. The same happens for derived classes that have the same parameters (in their constructor) with that of their respective base class. However, I cannot instantiate a derived class that has different number of parameters (in its constructor) from its base class.

For example:

- h file

```c
// CYH.h file
#ifndef __CYH_H__
#define __CYH_H__

#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
  Base(double);
  ~Base();
  double A;
  double getA();
  void setA(double);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   Derived(double, double);
   ~Derived();

   double B;
};
#endif
```

- cpp file

```c
// cyh.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "include/cyh.h"

Base::Base(double a)
{
    A = a;
}

Base::~Base()
{
}

double Base::getA(){
    return A;
}

void Base::setA(double a_){
    A = a_;
}

Derived::Derived(double a, double b) : Base(a)
{
    B = b;
}

Derived::~Derived()
{
}
```

- and pyx file

```py
cdef extern from "include/cyh.h":
    cdef cppclass Base:
        Base(double)
        double getA()
        void setA(double)

    cdef cppclass Derived(Base):
         Derived(double, double)

cdef class cyBase:
    cdef Base *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, double a):
        if type(self) is cyBase:
            self.thisptr = new Base(a)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if type(self) is cyBase:
            del self.thisptr

    @property
    def A(self):
        return self.thisptr.getA()

    @A.setter
    def A(self, value):
        self.thisptr.setA(value)


cdef class cyDerived(cyBase):
    cdef Derived *thisptrDerived
    def __cinit__(self, double a, double b):
        if type(self) is cyDerived:
            self.thisptrDerived = self.thisptr = new Derived(a, b)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if type(self) is cyDerived:
            del self.thisptrDerived
```

It compiles and the pyd builds successfully. However, when I am trying to instantiate the cyDerived class with:

```py
mycyObj = cyDerived(a=2., b=3.)
```

I get the following error:

```py
__cinit__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'b'
```

Ant idea what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That probably solves your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091422/5769463

Comment: Many thanks for your comment and the link. I used *args and **kwards in the base class as pointed here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/N-jXUWLzd6o. However, it is said that this might come with an efficiency penalty (I do not understand why). I wonder whether there is a more efficient way.

Comment: One option would be to "anticipate" `b` in the Base-class constructor and to disregard it there - but this mades code less clean, so I would do it onl< if there is really an issue with performance https://stackoverflow.com/a/13811280/5769463

Comment: I have used *args and **kwards instead. Why this would affect performance? And where? During class instantiation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is a quite interesting question: What is the performance penalty for using `*args`,  `**kwargs`and for which scenarios it should be taken into consideration?

From the theoretical point of view, there is the following additional work which needs to be done by the constructor of the `cyBase` class (every time it is called), if the `*args`, `**kwargs` solution is used:

1. get pointers to   `args` and `kwargs`  and register these references in the garbage collector,
2. check the dictionary (some overhead),
3. when no longer needed, unregister the references in the garbage collector, so this dictionary can be destroyed.

My assumption would be, that registering/unregistering could be a problem, because a reference update needs to acquire GIL. It is desirable to do this as infrequently as possible.

The solution without `*args` seems to be able to work without the need to change the reference-counter.

So far my theory, but I would like to see some empirical results, which might be quite surprising, so if you have some data, please share it with us.

---

Code to reproduce my results:

```
#no_kwargs.pyx:
cdef class cyBase:
    def __cinit__(self, double a):
        pass

cdef class cyDerived:
    def __cinit__(self, double a):
        self.a=a


#kwargs.pyx
cdef class cyBase:
    def __cinit__(self,  *argv, **kwargs):
        pass

cdef class cyDerived:
    def __cinit__(self, double a):
        self.a=a
```

Run it with

```
python -m cython XXX.pyx
```

and compare the resulting c-files. The differences are basically in `cyBase::__cinit__()` where the whole reference counting happens:

```
static int __pyx_pw_4test_6cyBase_1__cinit__(PyObject *__pyx_v_self, PyObject *__pyx_args, PyObject *__pyx_kwds) {
   ...
  __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_args);  // <----------- HERE
  __pyx_v_argv = __pyx_args;
   ...

  /* function exit code */
  __Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_v_argv); // <----------- HERE
  ...
  return __pyx_r;
}
```

`kwargs` seems to be unused here.

Comment: Hi ead, many thanks for your valuable answer. Actually, in the cyDerived class, I store a lot of data which are then passed to numerical solvers for computations. However, I need approx 100 instances of this class max for each of my simulations. I did a bench test with both methods, in a loop, I instantiated 1000 classes with both methods and it took exactly the same time. However, as you suggested, I will now use the solution without *args.